# How can I add database query data into the textbox?

Tags: c#, database, oledb

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        // modify the connection string and include any additional required properties for your database
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            @"Data Source=C:\Users\Dastgeer\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UrduStemmerProject\UrduStemmerProject\Resources\ProjectDatbase.mdb";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(@"SELECT PreFix FROM UrduStemmerTbl WHERE (word = '"+InputWord+"')");
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(@"SELECT Stem FROM UrduStemmerTbl WHERE (word = '" + InputWord + "')");
            cmd2.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd3 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(@"SELECT PostFix FROM UrduStemmerTbl WHERE (word = '" + InputWord + "')");
            cmd3.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //Text boxes names are

            //prefixOutput.Text =;
            //stemOutput.Text = ;               
            //postfixOutput.Text = ;

            MessageBox.Show("Data Stemmed!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to data source");
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `ExecuteNonQuery` for a `SELECT` statement. This method just executes your query, it doesn't return any data or something.

Looks like your queries returns one row with one column, you can use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar.aspx) method instead.

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

By the way, you can combine all `OleDbCommand` objects into one since you query the same table for different columns.

```
using(var conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
      cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT PreFix, Stem, PostFix FROM UrduStemmerTbl WHERE word = ?";
      cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = InputWord;
      // I assume your column type
      conn.Open();
      using(var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
           if(dr.Read())
           {
              prefixOutput.Text = dr.GetString(0);
              stemOutput.Text = dr.GetString(1);
              postfixOutput.Text = dr.GetString(2);
           }
      }
}
```